# Store Image path in database

Tags: android-sqlite

I am making a app in which I am retrieving data from Database in List View.
I want to have different picture with each data I retrieve from database in list View.
What I am trying to do is to save my pictures in drawable folder of my app and want to save image path in database and retrieve my image from saved path.
I searched lot on internet but couldn't get appropriate solution.
Somebody please show me appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already have solved this problem,
but after looking for it myself i found a solution.

what i did was use [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/android-read-file-from-assets.html).

i stored my images in a subfolder in "Assets" and this works like a charm,
don't know how many images it can hold in total, but i'll find out eventually i guess xD